# django rest framework: can we directly use Serializers class rather than extending

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a class as below and later use serializer to get the python datatypes:

```
from datetime import datetime
from rest_framework import serializers

class Comment(object):
    def __init__(self, email, content, created=None):
        self.email = email
        self.content = content
        self.created = created or datetime.now()
```

and created an object:

```
comment = Comment(email='leila@example.com', content='foo bar')

serializer = serializers.Serializer(comment).data
```

returns empty ReturnDict:

```
   ReturnDict()
```

whereas:

if i define a class which extends serializers.Serializer

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    pass
```

and then

```
serializer = CommentSerializer(comment).data

ReturnDict([('email', 'leila@example.com'),
            ('content', 'foo bar'),
            ('created', '2018-04-01T03:33:58.627773Z')])
```

Why serializers.Serializer works only when we extend it

Comment: I think its designed like that

Comment: so basically if i dont need any validation and i only want to convert to json then just put pass